# How to combine and sort different dataframes into one?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given two dataframes, which may have completely different schemas, except for a index column (`timestamp` in this case), such as df1 and df2 below:

df1:

```
timestamp | length | width
    1     |   10   |  20
    3     |    5   |   3
```

df2:

```
timestamp |  name    | length
    0     | "sample" |    3
    2     | "test"   |    6
```

How can I combine these two dataframes into one that would look something like this:

df3:

```
timestamp |     df1        |     df2
          | length | width |   name   | length  
    0     |   null |  null | "sample" |    3
    1     |   10   |  20   |   null   |   null
    2     |   null |  null | "test"   |    6
    3     |    5   |   3   |   null   |   null
```

I am extremely new to spark, so this might not actually make a lot of sense. But the problem I am trying to solve is: I need to combine these dataframes so that later I can convert each row to a given object. However, they have to be ordered by timestamp, so when I write these objects out, they are in the correct order.

So for example, given the `df3` above, I would be able to generate the following list of objects:

```
objs = [
 ObjectType1(timestamp=0, name="sample", length=3),
 ObjectType2(timestamp=1, length=10, width=20),
 ObjectType1(timestamp=2, name="test", length=6),
 ObjectType2(timestamp=3, length=5, width=3)
]
```

Perhaps combining the dataframes does not make sense, but how could I sort the dataframes individually and somehow grab the `Row`s  from each one of them ordered by `timestamp` globally?

P.S.: Note that I repeated `length` in both dataframes. That was done on purpose to illustrate that they may have columns of same name and type, but represent completely different data, so merging schema is not a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a full outer join, possibly renaming one of the columns, something like `df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("length","length2"), Seq("timestamp"),"full_outer")`

See this example, built from yours (just less typing)

```
// data shaped as your example
case class t1(ts:Int, width:Int,l:Int)
case class t2(ts:Int, width:Int,l:Int)
// create data frames
val df1 = Seq(t1(1,10,20),t1(3,5,3)).toDF
val df2 = Seq(t2(0,"sample",3),t2(2,"test",6)).toDF
df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("l","l2"),Seq("ts"),"full_outer").sort("ts").show
+---+-----+----+------+----+                                                    
| ts|width|   l|  name|  l2|
+---+-----+----+------+----+
|  0| null|null|sample|   3|
|  1|   10|  20|  null|null|
|  2| null|null|  test|   6|
|  3|    5|   3|  null|null|
+---+-----+----+------+----+
```